# Sharing authentication with ASP.NET and Silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, wcf, security

I have an ASP.NET web app that includes some silverlight pages. First, the users authenticate using a common ASP.NET webform.

This would be the typical code for that:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(this.txtUsername.Text, false);
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(this.txtUsername.Text, false);
Response.Redirect("~/Private/Index.aspx");
```

Next, the user navigates to a page that cointains a Silverlight page. From that silverlight page, I need to call some WCF services securely.

The service contains this code:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://mydomain")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    public class ServiceWCF
    {
        public ServiceWCF()
        {
            System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;

            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User;
        }

        [OperationContract]
        [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Authenticated = true)]
        public List<Data> GetData()
        {
            // do things
        }
    }
```

And this is the way I call that method from the silverlight client:

```
MyWCFReference.ServiceWCFClient proxy = new MyWCFReference.ServiceWCFClient();

proxy.GetDataCompleted += new EventHandler<MyWCFReference.GetDataCompletedEventArgs>(proxy_GetDataCompleted);
proxy.GetDataAsync();
```

I followed this article to protect my webservices:
http://netpl.blogspot.com/2010_04_01_archive.html

But when I run my code, I get the error: **Request for principal permission failed.**

Any idea about how to solve it? Thaaankkss!!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set up a `clientaccesspolicy.xml` or `crossdomain.xml` file in the root of the domain where the WCF service is hosted to allow your Silverlight application access.

See this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for full details.

Comment: @xus - Oh well. It might be a good idea to add your code that tries to make the connection.

Comment: the problem was that the WCF services were in a diferent project (in the same solution). I moved the WCF services to the asp.net project, and now it works :)